# Not able to access parts of imported .PY in a .PSP

Tags: python, mod-python, python-server-pages

I'm trying to load a weather plugin for a website I'm working on.  The weather plugin is a separate weather.py file located at /var/www/piss/plugins/base/weather.py.  In the PSP it seems to import correctly, but I am unable to access any variables or objects from the weather.py plugin in the PSP.  Here's the code I have:

```
    ...HTML and CSS stuff...

<% 
sys.path.append('/var/www/piss/plugins/base/')
pwd = os.getcwd()
import sys, os
import string
from weather import weather
%>
            <%= pwd %>
            <%= html1 %>
            <%= currentWeather %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Piss + INK Version                     0.00001</div>
        <div id="bottom"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the weather.py code:

```
from basePlugin import plugin
import MySQLdb
import pywapi

class weather(plugin):
    """
    weather.py
    Built-in weather plugin.
    """
    def __init__(self,zipcode):
        self.zipcode = zipcode

#Tested without DB access
    #db=_mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="things",passwd="things",db="things")
    #zip="SELECT zipcode FROM "+currentUser+"\;"
    #c = db.cursor()
    #dbResult = c.execute (zip)
    wResult=pywapi.get_weather_from_google('05401')
    html1="""
<div class="weather">
Weather:<br />
"""
    print html1
    currently = wResult['current_conditions']
    currentWeather = currently['condition']
    print currentWeather
    print "<br />"

    if currentWeather == "Mostly Cloudy":
        print '<img src="themes/default/images/weather/cloudy.png" alt="cloudy">'

    if currentWeather == "Cloudy":
        print '<img src="themes/default/images/weather/cloudy.png" alt="cloudy">'

    if currentWeather == "Sunny":
        print '<img src="themes/default/images/weather/sunny.png" alt="sunny">'

    if currentWeather == "Showers":
        print '<img src="themes/default/images/weather/rain.png" alt="rain">'

#More conditions will be added in actual plugin.

print "</div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

PSP isn't particularly popular in the Python world, and for good reason. Pretty much any other templating system is a better choice. It's been a very long time since I looked at PSP, and I may be misremembering how it works, but I'm not sure you expect PSP to know that `pwd`, `html1` and `currentWeather` come from the `weather` class you imported from the `weather` module. I'm also not sure the `print` statements in the class are doing what you think they're doing, considering they're in the class body, not a method.

All in all I would suggest you pick a saner templating system. Django's templates, Mako, Jinja, anything but PSP.

Comment: Yes, I expected html1 and currentWeather to be available when the weather plugin is imported.  The print statements were just for testing the module.

Comment: The question is *why* you expect that. How is PSP to know you mean for `currentWeather` and `html1` to be taken from attributes of the `weather` class from the `weather` module?